# How to get JSDOM to work with typescript when unit testing with a Chai\Mocha setup?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mocha.js, chai, jsdom

I've been trying to get JSDOM to work in my typescript unit tests, but after many attempts, I keep getting the following error (or variants of the following error)

```
TypeError: _jsdom.JSDOM is not a constructor
```

The code snippet is the following

```
import React from 'react';

import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { mock, instance, verify, anyOfClass } from 'ts-mockito';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
import { TestApp } from '../ts/ExampleForTestingReact';

let rootContainer: HTMLDivElement;
const { window } = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
```

My package json is the following

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "4.3.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.6",
    "@types/jsdom": "^16.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.8.1",
    "typescript": "3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-table": "^1.16.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.11",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "mpx-dialog": "^1.1.12",
    "mpx-error-boundary": "^1.0.0",
    "mpx-multi-language": "^1.0.8",
    "mpx-react-page-components": "^1.0.3",
    "mpx-utilities": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "tableexport.jquery.plugin": "^1.10.20"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
  },
  "mocha": {
    "extension": [
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "spec": "wwwroot/ts-tests/**/*.test.tsx",
    "require": "wwwroot/ts-tests/babel-register.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "pack-dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "pack-prod": "webpack --mode production",
    "clean": "del /Q /F .\\wwwroot\\dist\\*.*"
  }
}
```

I've been trying to do the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45311836/4545812

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue. In the end I removed **jsdom-global**, and added **jsdom**. I've also added the test example, to help anyone who might hit similar issues when trying to test with jsdom and typescript.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { TestApp } from '../ts/ExampleForTestingReact';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            document: Document;
            window: Window;
            navigator: Navigator;
        }
    }
}

const { window } = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.document = window.document;
global.window = global.document.defaultView;


describe('App Component Testing', () => {
    it('Renders Hello World Title', () => {
        act(() => {
            ReactDOM.render(<TestApp />, global.document);
        });
        const h1: Element = global.document.querySelector('h1');
        expect(h1.textContent).to.equal('Hello World');
    });
});
```

The above isn't perfect, as I plan to move the following section into a shared file, since it will be used in every typescript test

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            document: Document;
            window: Window;
            navigator: Navigator;
        }
    }
}

const { window } = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.document = window.document;
global.window = global.document.defaultView;
```

A useful Stack Overflow question/answer that helped me with the above:

[How to prevent "Property '...' does not exist on type 'Global'" with jsdom and typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743131/how-to-prevent-property-does-not-exist-on-type-global-with-jsdom-and-t)